# How do I derive start and end dates from sequential transactions by multiple dimensions with overlapping time periods?

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm using Teradata 16.20. I have a large transaction table that contains records that look something like the below.

```
CALDR_DT    PERNR   LOC MATNR
11/1/2019   111 L1  M1
11/2/2019   111 L1  M1
11/3/2019   111 L1  M1
11/4/2019   999 L1  M1
11/5/2019   999 L1  M1
11/6/2019   999 L1  M1
11/7/2019   111 L1  M1
11/8/2019   111 L1  M1
11/9/2019   111 L1  M1
11/10/2019  111 L1  M1
```

[image: table1]

The desired output is:

```
STRT_DT END_DT  PERNR   LOC MATNR
11/1/2019   11/3/2019   111 L1  M1
11/4/2019   11/6/2019   999 L1  M1
11/7/2019   12/31/9999  111 L1  M1
```

[image: tabl2]

I've been able to get there with cursors but it takes way too long so I was wondering if this could be done in a query with something like UNBOUNDED PRECEDING etc... but I'm not really familiar with those functions.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: What if there's a missing date, e.g. no row for `11/8/2019`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can use the difference of row numbers:

```
select pernr, matr, min(CALDR_DT), max(CALDR_DT)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by matnr order by CALDR_DT) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by matnr, pernr order by CALDR_DT) as seqnum_1
      from t
     ) t
group by (seqnum - seqnum_1), matnr, pernr;
```

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know this problem had a name too. Just tested this on the actual tables and results are exactly what we are looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's not really *gaps-and-islands*, it's *normalizing overlapping rows*. Teradata has a nice SQL extension to solve this, but it only works on PERIODs:

```
SELECT NORMALIZE -- normalize overlapping periods
   PERIOD(CALDR_DT, CALDR_DT+1) AS pd -- make the date a single day PERIOD
  ,PERNR
  ,LOC
  ,MATNR
FROM mytable
```

This results in a PERIOD, but you can split it back to two seperate columns:

```
SELECT 
   Begin(pd)
  ,Last(pd)
  ,PERNR
  ,LOC
  ,MATNR
FROM
 (
   SELECT NORMALIZE -- normalize overlapping periods
      PERIOD(CALDR_DT, CALDR_DT+1) AS pd -- make the date a single day PERIOD
     ,PERNR
     ,LOC
     ,MATNR
   FROM mytable
 ) AS dt
```